# Reference to unknown entity: java.lang.Integer

Tags: java, spring, spring-data

I'm having simple `@Entity` class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
@Getter       
class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private final Integer userID;    
    private final String username;   
}
```

And another one, that should hold foreign key to it

```
@Getter
@Builder
@Entity
class Task {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private final Integer taskID;

    private final String title;
    private final String details;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    @JoinTable(name = "user", joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "userID")})
    private final Integer userID;
}
```

The point is - `User` and `Task` classes are in separated packages and both are package scoped. Means I **can't** simply write

```
@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
@JoinTable(name = "user", joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "userID")})
private final User user;
```

And thats why I'm getting

```
@OneToOne or @ManyToOne on com.johndoe.teamplanner.task.domain.Task.userID references an unknown entity: java.lang.Integer
```

Is there a workaround, to achieve what I need? Create relationship between 2 entities that are in separated packages and with package scope?

Comment: An Integer is not an entity. Only entities can be annotated with ManyToOne.

Comment: Well, did u read my question? I'm aware of that, I'm looking for a workaround. Entity I want to reference here is another package, and has package-scope.

Comment: By design, you prevented yourself to be able to reference User from Task. So you can't use associations anymore. The workaround is to not use ManyToOne. Treat all columns as simple values, and thus don't annotate them with ManyToOne. This will make your life much more complex than necessary, but it's your choice. (If you're aware of that, why are you annotating an Integer with ManyToOne?)

Comment: I'v tried hexagonal architecture, where I divide application into smaller packages, `Task` and `User` were just an example, I could make them in one scope, but it will means my whole application will be in one scope, because I have model with many relationships. I'v tried `Integer` to simply use only related class id, instead of whole class, but I guess that wont work so easy too.

Comment: I don't know anything about hexagonal architecture. Architectures promoting isolated islands provide some advantages, but also major pain points. If all the entities are part of a unique application sharing a unique database anyway, the pain points will probably be more important than the advantages, especially when using JPA. If you were designing isolated microservices, each with their own database and development cycle, then decoupling would make more sense.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following alternatives:

- The obvious one: change the accessor of the class `User` to `public`. But, if you asked this is probably because you couldn't change it because you don't have the source code.
- Decompile the `User` .class file in order to get the source. If User isn't so complex, you probably could try this. Then, change the accessor to `public`.
- Generate your own version of the `User` class and use yours for persistence and the other one for the functionalities it provides.
- Map the `userID` in `Task` class just as an Integer and assure by code that you never assign a value that isn't a valid userID: `@Column private Integer userID;`. If you are using JPA to generate the tables, then you need to add manually the foreign key in the database to assure the integrity of your data.

I hope some of these solutions could help.

Comment: One question - how will last point be reflected in database? By using `@ManyToOne` etc, I'm getting foreign key on this column right? If I dont use that, my database will be just set of tables that are not connected?

Comment: @Weeedooo JPA shouldn't be the tool that creates your database schema. It can do that for simple throwaway demo applications, but for something real, you should create the schema, document it, add the necessary constraints and indices, migrate the data from one version of the schema to the other, etc. Use a tool designed to do that, like FlywayDB.

Comment: @Weeedooo, I just edited the post to answer to your comment.